# Issue with PHP and Postgres Queries

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to pull data from a postgress table using PHP. I'm supplying parameters to a query, and though I know there should be data in the table returned the returned array is empty.

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
      // Connecting, selecting database
$dbconn = pg_connect(***My connection details***)
          or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());


$lat1 = 50.5;
$lat2 = 58.0;
$lng1 = -3.5;
$lng2 = -7.0;

$colour_points = 'SELECT lat,lng,price,address_string FROM house_price_data_db.main where lat>=$1 and lat<=$2 and lng>=$3 and lng<=$4';
$result_pinpoints_points = pg_query_params($dbconn,$colour_points,array($lat1,$lat2,$lng1,$lng2)) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
$pin_points_array = array();

while($r = pg_fetch_assoc($result_pinpoints_points)) {
    $pin_points_array[] = $r;
}

header( "Content-type: application/json" ); // set the header to json 
echo(json_encode(array_values($pin_points_array), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)); // this will return json
pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

Any suggestions on how to solve/fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to test the query with the parameters directly on the database?

Comment: Can you specify some values for `$1`,`$2`,`$3`,`$4`??

Comment: The values are specified as $lat1,$lat2,$lng1,$lng2 as per the line defined `$result_pintpoints_points`. I figured out where I went wrong and explained below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a simple typo.

```
'SELECT lat,lng,price,address_string FROM house_price_data_db.main where lat>=$1 and lat<=$2 and lng**>=**$3 and lng**<=**$4';
```

Should have been:

```
'SELECT lat,lng,price,address_string FROM house_price_data_db.main where lat>=$1 and lat<=$2 and lng**<=**$3 and lng**>=**$4';
```

The equality/less-than/greater-than symbols for the last 2 inputs needed to be changed as otherwise there would be no output. It was saying if >-4 and <-7 which logically makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql comes with a handy set of [geometric types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html) and [functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html). Instead of storing latitude and longitude in two fields you can use the `point` type and -- even better -- create a [`latlong` domain over point](https://gist.github.com/chanmix51/1999886).

Using this, your query becomes something like:

```
select position, price,address_string FROM house_price_data_db.main where position <@ box($1, $2, $3, $4);
```

You can even aggregate results directly in SQL and even turn them to JSON:

```
with
  result as (
    select 
      array_agg(main) 
    from 
      house_price_data_db.main
    where position <@ box($1, $2, $3, $4)
  )
select row_to_json(result) from result;
```